# An efficient graph algorithm that satisfies the following conditions?

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, graph-theory, matching

Given an undirected graph with n vertices, we need to select some edges [say number of edges = m  { m>=1 and m<=floor(n/2)} ] in a way such that they do not share any common vertex and the sum of weights of all selected edges is maximized.
We need to find the maximimum sum for all number of selected edges(1 to n/2).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a look at this link to see the kinds of questions that we can help with: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Basically we want maximum weight matching for all number of edges (1 to n/2)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching . I found this link useful. I'd be glad if someone could help with the implementation of these algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

There are already polynomial-time algorithms for the problem.

It the graph is bipartite, network flow and Hungarian algorithm can do it.

Otherwise, the blossom algorithm could construct maximum matchings on general graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I want to maximize the sum  of weight associated with selected edges too  !

Comment: It's also applicable but much more complex. See http://jorisvr.nl/article/maximum-matching and http://uoj.ac/submission/16359.